# How can I add Ubuntu entry to a Windows 10 boot manager on a UEFI system while EasyBCD does not work on EFI Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I want to dual boot ubuntu along with my windows 10 os which is installed on the first storage device. The system is UEFI and GPT based. I installed the ubuntu to the second storage device, created swap, EFI, and ext4 root partitions for ubuntu while installing all on the second storage device. So basically I don't want the grub bootloader because I do not prefer using it. So I want to add ubuntu to windows bootloader. Googled about it a lot and found almost no relevant answer, they are all about MBR and bios systems. So here you can see easyBCD is not working as windows in EFI mode. is there any fix for this so I can have ubuntu to the windows 10 boot manager?

EasyBCD error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpbZ6.png